# Include php file in html page

Tags: php, html, xml

I'm working with XML and PHP to populate a web form drop down box.

I have a html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>

</head>

<body>
<header>
<h1>Title</h1>
</header>

    <form>
        <div id ="select xml">
            <?php include 'dropdown.php'; ?>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

and I am hoping to include the following PHP to generate the actual box with the file names of the XML.

```
<?php
//echo(substr(glob("xml/*.xml")[0],4));

echo  "<p>
      <label>Select list</label><br>
      <select id = \"selectxml\">
      <option value'0'>--Please Select--</option>";

        $count = count(glob("xml/*.xml"));
        $files = glob("xml/*.xml");
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            //echo(substr($files[$i],4));
            //echo "<br>";
        $filename = (substr($files[$i],4));
        echo "<option value=$i+1>$filename</option>";   
        }     

echo  "</select><br>
      <br>
      </p>";
?>
```

I'm aware the PHP isnt perfect, but it works.

The issue is that the Include HTML does not work when I run the page - any ideas?

Comment: be default, your server will NOT process php code in a file with .html extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the extension to **.php** and you will be okay .

When the page have **.html** extension, the web server doesn't recognize it as a **PHP** file, and you can't use **PHP** codes in it. and any **PHP** code, will be processed as a plain text .

I mean when you put :

```
<?php echo "hello" ?>
```

in a **HMTL** page, browser will show :

```
<?php echo "hello" ?>
```

But, if the page have **.php** extension, browser will show :

```
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename your html page from `.html` to `.php`

Answer (score 0):

it;s impossible, but with [jQuery.load](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/load/&ei=JWjiUsKdEaSJ5ATSvYGYCw&usg=AFQjCNEM5SkfmtKjdrVHvSlzndSIS3K-Dg&sig2=lnBXXAIKez1V56oO4sG_eg&bvm=bv.59930103,d.bGE) function you can do this :

```
$("#select-xml").load("dropdown.php");
```

Comment: because the script is executed **after** processing the page by web server . its only working just if the *dropdown.php* contains html , NOT php

Comment: `dropdown.php` result is html elements like `echo "<option value=$i+1>$filename</option>";` ,  i did :)

Comment: `echo` means **nothing** to web server if the file is **.html**